# Casting regex match to String

Tags: regex, scala

I created a simple code in Scala that checks whether an input is correctly formatted as HH:mm. I expect the code to result in an Array of valid strings. However, what I'm getting as a result is of type `Any = Array()`, which is problematic as when I try to print that result I get something like that:
`[Ljava.lang.Object;@32a59591`.

I guess it's a simple problem but being a Scala newbie I didn't manage to solve it even after a good few hours of googling and trial & error.

```
val scheduleHours = if (inputScheduleHours == "") {
  dbutils.notebook.exit(s"ERROR: Missing param value for schedule hours.")
}
else {
  val timePattern = """^((?:[0-30]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$""".r
  val inputScheduleHoursParsed = inputScheduleHours.split(";").map(_.trim)
  
  for (e <- inputScheduleHoursParsed) yield e match {
    case timePattern(e) => e.toString
    case _ => dbutils.notebook.exit(s"ERROR: Wrong param value for schedule hours: '${inputScheduleHours}'")
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your regex pattern is correct. It passes values like `39:45`, and the `^` and `$` anchors are unneeded. But other than that, the posted code appears to work for me. **Note**: use `mkString` when printing an `Array`.

Comment: When I try to print the result with mkString I'm getting this error:  `error: value mkString is not a member of Any`
As for the regex, thanks for pointing this out. I fixed it already and then lost the changes while playing with the Array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some branches return the result you want and others return `dbutils.notebook.exit` which (I think) returns `Unit`. Scala must pick a type for the result that is compatible with both `Unit` and `Array[String]`, and `Any` is the only one that fits.

One solution is to add a compatible value after the calls to `dbutils.notebook.exit`, e.g.

```
val scheduleHours = if (inputScheduleHours == "") {
  dbutils.notebook.exit(s"ERROR: Missing param value for schedule hours.")
  Array.empty[String]
}
```

Then all the branches return `Array[String]` so that will be the type of the result.